# setting custom adapters to grid views

Tags: android

In my main activity I have a spinner which contains three categories(All,Horizontal and Vertical), below that there is a gridView. I have some images in resource folder which are for both vertical and horizontal mode. I need to set the images to gridView according to selected item on spinner. I am able to set one category into gridView (for e.g all category). When selecting other category gridView did not update. For updating the gridView what should I do? plz help me?

I tried it by using placing three gridViews in my activity and set their visibility to gone, and make it visible when setting adapter(I used three separate adapters but not working.

My code is given below.

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner vsel;
    ArrayList<String> vimage = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> all = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> himage = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> allid = new ArrayList<Integer>();   
    ArrayList<Integer> hid = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> vid = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
    ArrayList<Integer> tot = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
    ArrayList<String> spinner = new ArrayList<String>();
    GridView gv,sgv,gv1,gv2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gv1 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
        gv2 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView3);
        Class resources = R.drawable.class;
        java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields = resources.getFields();
         for(java.lang.reflect.Field field : fields)
        {
             try {
                    if(field.getName().contains("split"))
                    {
                        all.add(field.getName());
                        allid.add(field.getInt(fields));
                    }
                    if(field.getName().contains("splith"))
                        {
                            //String iname = field.getName();
                            himage.add(field.getName());
                            hid.add(field.getInt(fields));
                        }
                    if(field.getName().contains("splitv"))
                        {
                            vimage.add(field.getName());
                            vid.add(field.getInt(fields));
                        }
                        /*else
                        {
                            all.add(field.getName());
                            allid.add(field.getInt(fields));
                        }*/
                    }
                 catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
         System.out.println("All arraylist-> " + allid);
         System.out.println("Horizontal arraylist-> " + hid);
         System.out.println("Vertical arraylist-> " + vid);
      //  String[] viewsel = {"All","Vertical","Horizontal"};
         spinner.add("All");
         spinner.add("Vertical");
         spinner.add("Horizontal");
        vsel = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
        ArrayAdapter<String> sadpater = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinner);
        sadpater.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        vsel.setAdapter(sadpater);
        vsel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                String item = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if(item.equals("All"))
                {
                    gv2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    gv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,item,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    gv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     gv.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter(MainActivity.this,allid));
                }
                if(item.equals("Vertical"))
                {
                    gv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    gv2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    gv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,item,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                     gv1.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter1(MainActivity.this,vid));
                }
                 if(item.equals("Horizontal"));
                {
                    gv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    gv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,item,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    gv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     gv2.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter3(MainActivity.this,hid));
                }
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }


    public class AppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        ArrayList<Integer> dirsTemp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        public AppsAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<Integer> allid)
        {

            Log.d("In appsadapter1 all","Hii");
            dirsTemp = allid;

            context = c;

        }


        //---returns the number of images---

        public final int getCount() {

            return dirsTemp.size();


        }

         //---returns the ID of an item--- 

        public final Object getItem(int position) {
            return dirsTemp.get(position);
        }

        public final long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //final File f = (File) getItem(position);
            int i = (Integer) getItem(position);
            System.out.println("Dirstemp->"+dirsTemp);
            ImageView iv;
            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                    iv = new ImageView(context);
                    //iv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            }

            else
            {
                    iv = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            iv.setImageResource(dirsTemp.get(position));


            return iv;          
        }   
    }






    public class AppsAdapter1 extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context1;
        ArrayList<Integer> dirsTemp1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        public AppsAdapter1(Context c,ArrayList<Integer>vid) {
            Log.d("In appsadapter1 vertical","Hii");
            dirsTemp1 = vid;

            context1 = c;

        }


        //---returns the number of images---

        public final int getCount() {

            return dirsTemp1.size();


        }

         //---returns the ID of an item--- 

        public final Object getItem(int position) {
            return dirsTemp1.get(position);
        }

        public final long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //final File f = (File) getItem(position);
            int i = (Integer) getItem(position);
            ImageView iv1;
            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                    iv1 = new ImageView(context1);
                    //iv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            }

            else
            {
                    iv1 = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            iv1.setImageResource(dirsTemp1.get(position));


            return iv1;         
        }   
    }  




    public class AppsAdapter3 extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context2;
        ArrayList<Integer> dirsTemp2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        public AppsAdapter3(Context c,ArrayList<Integer>hid) {
            Log.d("In appsadapter1 horizontal","Hii");
            dirsTemp2 = hid;
            context2 = c;


        }


        //---returns the number of images---

        public final int getCount() {

            return dirsTemp2.size();


        }

         //---returns the ID of an item--- 

        public final Object getItem(int position) {
            return dirsTemp2.get(position);
        }

        public final long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //final File f = (File) getItem(position);
            int i = (Integer) getItem(position);
            ImageView iv2;
            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                    iv2 = new ImageView(context2);
                    //iv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            }

            else
            {
                    iv2 = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            iv2.setImageResource(dirsTemp2.get(position));


            return iv2;         
        }   
    }


}
```

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
gv.postInvalidate();

Comment: tried it but not working............. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need three gridViews and three adapters. One is enough. When changing category from spinner , refresh the list `allid, vid, hid` (used in Adapter to display gridview) and then `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

EDIT: try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


    public class ddsds extends Activity {
   Spinner vsel;
   ArrayList<String> vimage = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> all = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> himage = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<Integer> allid = new ArrayList<Integer>();   
   ArrayList<Integer> hid = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ArrayList<Integer> vid = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
   ArrayList<Integer> tot = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
   ArrayList<String> spinner = new ArrayList<String>();
   GridView gv;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

       Class resources = R.drawable.class;
       java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields = resources.getFields();
        for(java.lang.reflect.Field field : fields)
       {
            try {
                   if(field.getName().contains("split"))
                   {
                       all.add(field.getName());
                       allid.add(field.getInt(fields));
                   }
                   if(field.getName().contains("splith"))
                       {
                           //String iname = field.getName();
                           himage.add(field.getName());
                           hid.add(field.getInt(fields));
                       }
                   if(field.getName().contains("splitv"))
                       {
                           vimage.add(field.getName());
                           vid.add(field.getInt(fields));
                       }
                       /*else
                       {
                           all.add(field.getName());
                           allid.add(field.getInt(fields));
                       }*/
                   }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
               }
       }
        System.out.println("All arraylist-> " + allid);
        System.out.println("Horizontal arraylist-> " + hid);
        System.out.println("Vertical arraylist-> " + vid);
     //  String[] viewsel = {"All","Vertical","Horizontal"};
        spinner.add("All");
        spinner.add("Vertical");
        spinner.add("Horizontal");
       vsel = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
       ArrayAdapter<String> sadpater = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spinner);
       sadpater.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       vsel.setAdapter(sadpater);
       ArrayList<String> list ; 
       AppsAdapter adapter = null; 

       vsel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                   int position, long id) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               //String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
               String item = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();

               if(item.equals("All"))
               {
                   list = allid;
               }
               if(item.equals("Vertical"))
               {
                   list = vid;
               }
                if(item.equals("Horizontal"));
               {
                   list = hid));
               }

               if (adapter = null ) {
                   adapter = new AppsAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
                   gv.setAdapter(adapter);
               }
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }

           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> view) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }
       });
   }


   public class AppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
       private Context context;
       ArrayList<Integer> dirsTemp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       public AppsAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<Integer> allid)
       {

           Log.d("In appsadapter1 all","Hii");
           dirsTemp = allid;

           context = c;

       }


       //---returns the number of images---

       public final int getCount() {

           return dirsTemp.size();


       }

        //---returns the ID of an item--- 

       public final Object getItem(int position) {
           return dirsTemp.get(position);
       }

       public final long getItemId(int position) {

           return position;
       }

       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           //final File f = (File) getItem(position);
           int i = (Integer) getItem(position);
           System.out.println("Dirstemp->"+dirsTemp);
           ImageView iv;
           if (convertView == null) 
           {
                   iv = new ImageView(context);
                   //iv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
           }

           else
           {
                   iv = (ImageView) convertView;
           }
           iv.setImageResource(dirsTemp.get(position));


           return iv;          
       }   
   }




}










}
```

Comment: list = null.. 
 what is list? array list?

Comment: yeh i tried it only displays horizontal category... no other categories were not displaying....